# Syntax error on token `else`

Tags: java, syntax-error

I am very new to coding and I keep getting this error I really need help with it. This is my code:

```
public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack stack, Entity entity, int slot, String type){
    if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumHelmet || stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumChestplate || stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumBoots) {
        return "halo:textures/models/armor/Titanium1.png";
    }
    if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings); {
        return "halo:textures/models/armor/Titanium_layar_2.png";
    } else { //<------ Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
        return null; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is an extra semicolon after the condition:

```
 if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings);
```

Remove it. Statement will be like this:

```
 if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings); {
```

to

```
if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings) {
```

This is bad, because

```
if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings); {
   //do stuff...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings)  {
}
   //The above EMPTY block is only executed when the 
   //if evaluates to true. The below is ALWAYS executed.
{ 
   //do stuff
}
```

And that is bad.

Comment: Why does Java allow this as valid syntax when clearly there is no point? Executing an empty block based on a boolean condition? Who needs that?!

Comment: It doesn't execute an empty block. It's equivalent to it. Either way, agreed: It's pointless. The only use case I can think of is when the condition also does something, but it would be confusing to do that anyway.

Comment: I thought about the side-effect case but Java can still show compilation error, and IDEs could offer quick fix "Remove if check keeping side effects". At the very least Java could make it invalid to enter a mere semicolon after an if check. Allowing this pointless syntax is a common source of confusion!

Answer (score 3):

There is a `;` at a wrong place IMHO

```
public String getArmorTexture(ItemStack stack, Entity entity, int slot, String type){
    if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumHelmet || stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumChestplate || stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumBoots) {
        return "halo:textures/models/armor/Titanium1.png";
    }
    if (stack.getItem() == halo.TitaniumLeggings) {
        return "halo:textures/models/armor/Titanium_layar_2.png";
    } else { //<------ Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
        return null; }
```

Should work. Don't put `;` at `if`-statements ;)