# Else Error When using If Else Statements

Tags: java, if-statement

Trying to get calculations to come up if within $50 there's no refund, if above $50 its the total tax minus $50, for some reason else is not taking here. Thoughts? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class germany {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //constants
        final double Tax_Rate = 0.10;  
        int Max_Tax = 50;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);


        //Variables 
        double purchases;  
        double taxespaid; 
        double taxOwed;

        //Request Input 
        System.out.print("Enter your total amount of purchases:"); 
        purchases = reader.nextDouble();



        taxespaid = purchases * Tax_Rate;

        taxOwed = taxespaid - Max_Tax;  

        if (Max_Tax <=taxespaid); {

            System.out.println("You are within $50 limit");

        } else if (Max_Tax <=taxespaid);    

            System.out.println("The amount is owed to you is $" + taxOwed);

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the semicolons after each of the `if` and `else if` conditions; they are acting as the bodies of the statement, and the `println` statements are always executing.

Comment: You're using twice the same condition.

Comment: Geez louise 13 upvotes for a single comment. Maybe I should move over to `Java`. `C#` is a barren wasteland in comparison.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error on token \`else\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746317/syntax-error-on-token-else)

Comment: How does this compile? I thought there should be a compilation error at `else if`...

Comment: @ADTC It doesn't compile. As soon as you remove the semi-colon after the first if, it compiles just fine. Still pointless until you eliminate the semi-colon after the else-if, too.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have

```
if (Max_Tax <=taxespaid); {
    System.out.println("You are within $50 limit");
} else if (Max_Tax <=taxespaid);    
    System.out.println("The amount is owed to you is $" + taxOwed);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if (Max_Tax <=taxespaid)  {
}

System.out.println("You are within $50 limit");

} else if (Max_Tax <=taxespaid)  {
}

System.out.println("The amount is owed to you is $" + taxOwed);
```

So your `System.out.println`s always execute, which is not what you want. And (in addition to the `System.out`s) *nothing* (the equivalent of an empty block) executes when either condition is met, which is also not what you want.

Eliminate the semi-colons between the conditions and their opening curly-braces (`{`), and *always* use curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a syntax error on your code, try typing it like this:

```
if (Max_Tax <= taxespaid)
{
     System.out.println("You are within $50 limit");

} 
else
{
     System.out.println("The amount is owed to you is $" + taxOwed);
}
```

For some Java tutorials and basic programing  you can visit: http://www.learnjavaonline.org

Comment: It's a semantic error, not a syntax error.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It is a semantic error. Great thing that you pointed it out.

Comment: To be fair, it's both. The syntax error is having an else statement that hangs (not attached to an if statement). The semantic error is the semicolons (valid syntax but not what you want).